# How can I use Chinese letters for locals lua

Tags: lua, local-variables, roblox

im trying to make locals with Chinese letters

```
local 屁 = p 
or 
屁 = p
```

none of those work
any ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this as "`屁`" is not a valid Lua identifier.

Lua identifiers can only have letters, numbers and underscores and must not start with a number.

However, you can create a table with a key `屁`:

```
local chinese_letters = {
    ["屁"] = p
}
```

And access it as `chinese_letters["屁"]`, for example

```
local chinese_letters = {
    ["屁"] = 10
}

print(chinese_letters["屁"])
```

By the way, the correct name for these chinese characters is [Hanzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters)